# Can't get z-index working properly

Tags: css, z-index

I'm having trouble getting the z-index for my bottom triangle on the sidebar to work properly. I need it to be underneath the header box so I can see the 3D effect.. any ideas?

The site is - http://www.dunkleysdairy.com

The sidebar is on the right (with yellow heading)

Comment: Please see: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/) for reasons why your post may need improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are trying to set the z-index of an element lower than the one it is nested in. This is not possible - see link for a graphical example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context

What you need to do is make sure the element you want to move backwards is not a child descendant of the item you expect to go in front.

In your particular case you would be able to remedy this by applying your styling of .heading to the h2.

Alternatively, you might consider using a psuedo-element for this so you don't have to add extra divs. Your html would just be:

```
<div class="heading">Title goes here</div>
```

Then you would add to your current .heading styling with this rule (making sure to keep relative:positioning on your .heading but removing any z-index from it):

```
.heading:before{
content:" "; display:block; position:absolute;
border-color: transparent #dfb704 transparent transparent; border-style: solid; border-width: 15px;
height: 0px; width: 0px; 
left: -15px; bottom: -15px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

This would set your triangle directly below your heading in the z-index stack.
Here's a quick example:
http://codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/Fprxk

Comment: This might be better as a comment on OpherV's answer rater than an answer in itself.

Comment: I've edited the answer so it is now a self contained answer rather than referencing OpherV's (which I'm assuming was the main issue with it).

Answer (score 0):

`frame` is a descendant of `heading`, and so the z-index property for `frame` affects it.
If you wish to provide them with a different z depth, you will need to place them on different branches of the DOM tree. For example: both can be child elements of `block`.